# str_replace in Common Lisp?

Tags: lisp, common-lisp

Is there some function similar to PHP's str_replace in Common Lisp?

http://php.net/manual/en/function.str-replace.php

Comment: Duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/90977/replace-char-in-emacs-lisp ?

Comment: It should be in common lisp and I don't want to install any additional libraries. I just have SLIME.

Comment: If you don't want elisp solutions, you shouldn't tag the question with elisp.

Comment: What do you mean by Lisp? I gather from the comments below that you mean CL. You should say that in the first place.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

There is a library called cl-ppcre:

```
(cl-ppcre:regex-replace-all "qwer" "something to qwer" "replace")
; "something to replace"
```

Install it via [quicklisp](http://quicklisp.org).

Comment: It should be in common lisp and I don't want to install any additional libraries. I just have SLIME.

Comment: Common lisp doesn't include perl-compatibe regular expressions because they became a standard feature years later. You can find a simple implementation of replace-string here: http://cl-cookbook.sourceforge.net/strings.html#manip

Comment: Useful note: if you're planning on replacing some text with backslashes, you'd better use answer below. I've tried replacing it with cl-ppcre, but it isn't straightforward, so actually function below was better suited for this job.

Answer (score 8):

I think there is no such function in the standard.  If you do not want to use a regular expression (cl-ppcre), you could use this:

```
(defun string-replace (search replace string &optional count)
  (loop for start = (search search (or result string)
                            :start2 (if start (1+ start) 0))
        while (and start
                   (or (null count) (> count 0)))
        for result = (concatenate 'string
                                  (subseq (or result string) 0 start)
                                  replace
                                  (subseq (or result string)
                                          (+ start (length search))))
        do (when count (decf count))
        finally (return-from string-replace (or result string))))
```

*EDIT:* Shin Aoyama pointed out that this does not work for replacing, e.g.,  `"\""` with `"\\\""` in `"str\"ing"`.   Since I now regard the above as rather cumbersome I should propose the implementation given in the [Common Lisp Cookbook](https://lispcookbook.github.io/cl-cookbook/strings.html#manipulating-parts-of-a-string), which is much better:

```
(defun replace-all (string part replacement &key (test #'char=))
  "Returns a new string in which all the occurences of the part 
is replaced with replacement."
  (with-output-to-string (out)
    (loop with part-length = (length part)
          for old-pos = 0 then (+ pos part-length)
          for pos = (search part string
                            :start2 old-pos
                            :test test)
          do (write-string string out
                           :start old-pos
                           :end (or pos (length string)))
          when pos do (write-string replacement out)
          while pos)))
```

I especially like the use of `with-output-to-string`, which generally performs better than `concatenate`.

Comment: Although the latter implementation hangs if *part* is the empty string. It should check for it, to be correct.

Answer (score 7):

If the replacement is only one character, which is often the case, you can use substitute:

```
(substitute #\+ #\Space "a simple example") => "a+simple+example"
```